# Proof or reject condition number if square matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, condition-number

I want to proof(if true) or reject:
For all A Square matrix nxn K(10A) = 10K(A), i think it's wrong since:
K(cA)=K(A) (refe [Show property of condition number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008227/show-property-of-condition-number?newreg=6e95fdf4d554484a8d887bb4a98af3c4))

if K(cA) == K(A) which is != from 10K(A), is my proof is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. To go into a bit more detail,
$$
\kappa(10A)=||10A|| \cdot ||(10A)^{-1}||=10||A|| \cdot 10^{-1}||A^{-1}||=||A|| \cdot ||A^{-1}|| = \kappa(A) \neq 10 \kappa(A).
$$